# Splitting String Value Using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have an input string value as below and would like to split on non-numeric literals like whitespace, characters,new line, comma, period, slashes, backslashes, etc.

For example my input value would be:

```
var list = 
'123
456 789
1234..5678//999
123aaa456'
```

I want the output value to be: 123, 456, 789, 1234, 5678, 999, 123, 456

I try to split it using the regex below but it keeps stopping on the second number...

```
var split= list.split(/[\s\t.,;:]+/);
```

Could anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/\D+/` === non-numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\D` to match any non-numeric character, or `\D+` to match one or more such characters together:

```
var split = list.split(/\D+/);
```

You said:

> I try to split it using the regex below but it keeps stopping on the second number...
>
> `var split= list.split(/[\s\t.,;:]+/);`

I don't see how it could stop on the second number: that regex would produce the output `["123", "456", "789", "1234", "5678//999", "123aaa456"]`, because your pattern doesn't include forward slashes or letters.

Comment: Thank you this is working. For some reason the javascript was not loaded correctly on the page I'm working on so returned wrong result..